# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION for FacesContext

Tags: jsf, weblogic-10.x

I get the below error once I start Weblogic server,

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x02a3f964, pid=22132, tid=24504
>
> JRE version: 6.0_29-b11
>
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.4-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
>
> Problematic frame:
>   j  javax.faces.context.FacesContext.()V+0
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    C:\Oracle\Middleware2\user_projects\domains\base_domain\hs_err_pid22132.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

Crash log is pasted below

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x32310800):  JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=24504, stack(0x320b0000,0x32100000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x29130000

    Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x290f0ce0, EDX=0x00000da3
ESP=0x320ff06c, EBP=0x320ff088, ESI=0x2912ffff, EDI=0x320ff08c
EIP=0x02a3f964, EFLAGS=0x00010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x320ff06c)
0x320ff06c:   290f0ce0 320ff08c 290f0fc0 00000000
0x320ff07c:   290f0ce0 00000000 320ff090 320ff0a0
0x320ff08c:   02a30364 00001fa0 02a302ff 32310800
0x320ff09c:   290f0ce0 320ff118 6d99ac3b 320ff0d4
0x320ff0ac:   320ff1e0 0000000a 290f0ce0 02a3d2f0
0x320ff0bc:   320ff198 00000000 32310800 00000004
0x320ff0cc:   32310800 32310800 32310800 3311f150
0x320ff0dc:   290f0ce0 00000000 320ff3c0 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x02a3f964)
0x02a3f944:   1c 24 e9 19 00 00 00 83 ec 08 dd 1c 24 e9 0e 00
0x02a3f954:   00 00 52 50 e9 07 00 00 00 50 e9 01 00 00 00 50
0x02a3f964:   0f b6 5e 01 46 ff 24 9d 90 c4 b1 6d 50 00 00 00
0x02a3f974:   7c ad ab 6d 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 83 ec 04 d9 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x290f0ce0 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
EDX=0x00000da3 is an unknown value
ESP=0x320ff06c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x32310800
EBP=0x320ff088 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x32310800
ESI=0x2912ffff is an unallocated location in the heap
EDI=0x320ff08c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x32310800


Stack: [0x320b0000,0x32100000],  sp=0x320ff06c,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
j  javax.faces.context.FacesContext.<clinit>()V+0
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfac3b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18c391]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfacbd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x7ddf7]
V  [jvm.dll+0x7ec5e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x7ef49]
V  [jvm.dll+0x7f066]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4d739]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4de9f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4e070]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4ac71]
j  com.sun.faces.util.Util.getApplicationMap()Ljava/util/Map;+2
j  com.sun.faces.util.Util.getPatternCache()Ljava/util/Map;+0
j  com.sun.faces.util.Util.split(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;+0
j  com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getOptionValue(Lcom/sun/faces/config/WebConfiguration$WebContextInitParameter;Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;+65
j  com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.<init>(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V+121
j  com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getInstance(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Lcom/sun/faces/config/WebConfiguration;+21
j  com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContextEvent;)V+56
j  weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+15
j  weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Lweblogic/security/subject/AbstractSubject;Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+34
j  weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Lweblogic/security/acl/internal/AuthenticatedSubject;Lweblogic/security/acl/internal/AuthenticatedSubject;Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+18
j  weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent()V+84
j  weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources()V+21
j  weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start()V+33
j  weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts()V+35
j  weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start()V+30
j  weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+4
j  weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(Lweblogic/application/utils/StateChange;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V+27
j  weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start([Lweblogic/application/Module;)V+8
j  weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start()V+8
j  weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start()V+4
j  weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+4
j  weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(Lweblogic/application/utils/StateChange;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V+27
j  weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start([Lweblogic/application/Module;)V+8
j  weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate()V+13
j  weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+4
j  weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(Lweblogic/application/utils/StateChange;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V+27
j  weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(Lweblogic/deploy/container/DeploymentContext;)V+55
j  weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(Lweblogic/deploy/container/DeploymentContext;)V+2
j  weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(Lweblogic/deploy/container/DeploymentContext;)V+11
j  weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(Lweblogic/deploy/container/DeploymentContext;)V+49
j  weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(Lweblogic/deploy/container/DeploymentContext;)V+104
j  weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle()V+91
j  weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+12
j  weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+6
j  weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(Lweblogic/management/deploy/internal/DeploymentAdapter;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+2
j  weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(Lweblogic/management/deploy/internal/AppTransition;)V+177
j  weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate()V+4
j  weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy()V+13
j  weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume()V+3
j  weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start()V+0
j  weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run()V+64
j  weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+34
j  weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run()V+42
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfac3b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18c391]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfade1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfae3b]
V  [jvm.dll+0xb5569]
V  [jvm.dll+0x118f14]
V  [jvm.dll+0x140fec]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]  endthreadex+0xa0
C  [kernel32.dll+0x133aa]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x38fe2]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x38fb5]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x31bf3400 JavaThread "net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@1669e7f" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24552, stack(0x35490000,0x354e0000)]
  0x31bf3000 JavaThread "[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=25636, stack(0x34430000,0x34480000)]
  0x31bf2800 JavaThread "[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=25540, stack(0x343a0000,0x343f0000)]
  0x31bf2400 JavaThread "[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24136, stack(0x34310000,0x34360000)]
  0x31bf1c00 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24084, stack(0x34280000,0x342d0000)]
  0x31bf1400 JavaThread "Thread-15" [_thread_blocked, id=23724, stack(0x341f0000,0x34240000)]
  0x31bef800 JavaThread "Thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=24600, stack(0x33c50000,0x33ca0000)]
  0x31bf1000 JavaThread "Thread-13" [_thread_in_native, id=23532, stack(0x341a0000,0x341f0000)]
  0x31bf0800 JavaThread "Timer-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24776, stack(0x33ec0000,0x33f10000)]
  0x31bf0400 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23808, stack(0x33e30000,0x33e80000)]
  0x31befc00 JavaThread "DoSManager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22444, stack(0x33ce0000,0x33d30000)]
  0x31bef000 JavaThread "VDE Transaction Processor Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22284, stack(0x33bc0000,0x33c10000)]
  0x328b0400 JavaThread "ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=22424, stack(0x33b30000,0x33b80000)]
  0x31d73c00 JavaThread "ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=23984, stack(0x33aa0000,0x33af0000)]
  0x32c7bc00 JavaThread "ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=24396, stack(0x33a10000,0x33a60000)]
  0x32906400 JavaThread "[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23968, stack(0x33380000,0x333d0000)]
  0x328fdc00 JavaThread "weblogic.timers.TimerThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24364, stack(0x331f0000,0x33240000)]
  0x32bf2800 JavaThread "weblogic.time.TimeEventGenerator" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24468, stack(0x32140000,0x32190000)]
=>0x32310800 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=24504, stack(0x320b0000,0x32100000)]
  0x3230e800 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22092, stack(0x32020000,0x32070000)]
  0x31e3f800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22044, stack(0x31f10000,0x31f60000)]
  0x011f1400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23240, stack(0x30f60000,0x30fb0000)]
  0x011e8c00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23500, stack(0x30e60000,0x30eb0000)]
  0x011e1c00 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22324, stack(0x30dd0000,0x30e20000)]
  0x011e0400 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=17000, stack(0x30d40000,0x30d90000)]
  0x011d3800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18812, stack(0x30c70000,0x30cc0000)]
  0x011d0800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23236, stack(0x30be0000,0x30c30000)]
  0x011a5400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=25240, stack(0x012a0000,0x012f0000)]
  0x011a0c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=36716, stack(0x01210000,0x01260000)]
  0x0130f000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=12184, stack(0x00230000,0x00280000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0119d400 VMThread [stack: 0x00530000,0x00580000] [id=5932]
  0x011fcc00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x30ff0000,0x31040000] [id=23368]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 78720K, used 69511K [0x04a30000, 0x09f90000, 0x0f4d0000)
  eden space 70016K,  93% used [0x04a30000, 0x08a53e28, 0x08e90000)
  from space 8704K,  44% used [0x09710000, 0x09acdf20, 0x09f90000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x08e90000, 0x08e90000, 0x09710000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 37994K [0x0f4d0000, 0x19f80000, 0x24a30000)
   the space 174784K,  21% used [0x0f4d0000, 0x119ea978, 0x119eaa00, 0x19f80000)
 compacting perm gen  total 72704K, used 72451K [0x24a30000, 0x29130000, 0x30a30000)
   the space 72704K,  99% used [0x24a30000, 0x290f0fd8, 0x290f1000, 0x29130000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x02a30000, 0x02cd0000, 0x04a30000)
 total_blobs=1691 nmethods=1478 adapters=156 free_code_cache=30807040 largest_free_block=192

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\bin\java.exe
0x77620000 - 0x777a0000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x76be0000 - 0x76cf0000     C:\windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x765b0000 - 0x765f7000     C:\windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x74b00000 - 0x74b6d000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\SYSFER.DLL
0x75c70000 - 0x75d10000     C:\windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76a10000 - 0x76abc000     C:\windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x764f0000 - 0x76509000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x76600000 - 0x766f0000     C:\windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x74ce0000 - 0x74d40000     C:\windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x74cd0000 - 0x74cdc000     C:\windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6db4f000     C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76140000 - 0x76240000     C:\windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x76700000 - 0x76790000     C:\windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x775f0000 - 0x775fa000     C:\windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x76510000 - 0x765ad000     C:\windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x6c170000 - 0x6c1a2000     C:\windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x75d10000 - 0x75d70000     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x74d40000 - 0x74e0c000     C:\windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x73b40000 - 0x73b8c000     C:\windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d850000 - 0x6d85c000     C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3d0000 - 0x6d3ef000     C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d420000 - 0x6d449000     C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\jre\bin\jdwp.dll
0x6d740000 - 0x6d746000     C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\jre\bin\npt.dll
0x6d890000 - 0x6d89f000     C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x6d2b0000 - 0x6d2b7000     C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\jre\bin\dt_socket.dll
0x75c30000 - 0x75c65000     C:\windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x76130000 - 0x76136000     C:\windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x74580000 - 0x745bc000     C:\windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x74570000 - 0x74575000     C:\windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x6d6b0000 - 0x6d6c3000     C:\Oracle\Middleware2\jdk160_29\jre\bin\net.dll
0x741f0000 - 0x741f6000     C:\windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x6c790000 - 0x6c7a0000     C:\windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x6c780000 - 0x6c790000     C:\windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x6c760000 - 0x6c772000     C:\windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x70d40000 - 0x70d84000     C:\windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x6c750000 - 0x6c758000     C:\windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x741d0000 - 0x741ec000     C:\windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x741c0000 - 0x741c7000     C:\windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x74140000 - 0x74146000     C:\windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x74150000 - 0x74188000     C:\windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x6d6d0000 - 0x6d6d9000     C:\Oracle\Middleware2\jdk160_29\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d609000     C:\Oracle\Middleware2\jdk160_29\jre\bin\management.dll
0x00850000 - 0x00855000     C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlserver_10.3\server\native\win\32\stackdump.dll
0x74550000 - 0x74566000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x74510000 - 0x7454b000     C:\windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x74080000 - 0x74097000     C:\windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x74360000 - 0x7436b000     C:\windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x741b0000 - 0x741bd000     C:\windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x74190000 - 0x741a2000     C:\windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x00a40000 - 0x00a45000     C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlserver_10.3\server\native\win\32\wlntio.dll
0x6d830000 - 0x6d838000     C:\Oracle\Middleware2\jdk160_29\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x75f30000 - 0x76050000     C:\windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
0x76cf0000 - 0x76cfc000     C:\windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
0x30ef0000 - 0x30f03000     C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlserver_10.3\server\native\win\32\wlfileio3.dll
0x76d00000 - 0x76d05000     C:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8453,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=48m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy -Xverify:none -ea -da:com.bea... -da:javelin... -da:weblogic... -ea:com.bea.wli... -ea:com.bea.broker... -ea:com.bea.sbconsole... -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.wsee.bind.suppressDeployErrorMessage=true -Dweblogic.wsee.skip.async.response=true -Dweblogic.management.discover=true -Dwlw.iterativeDev=true -Dwlw.testConsole=true -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=true -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_wls1036\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_wlp1036\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_oepe1111\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_ocm1033\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlportal_10.3\p13n\lib\system;C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlportal_10.3\light-portal\lib\system;C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlportal_10.3\portal\lib\system;C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlportal_10.3\info-mgmt\lib\system;C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlportal_10.3\analytics\lib\system;C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlportal_10.3\apps\lib\system;C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlportal_10.3\info-mgmt\deprecated\lib\system;C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlportal_10.3\content-mgmt\lib\system -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:\Oracle\Middleware2\wlportal_10.3\portal\lib\security 
java_command: weblogic.Server
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_wls1036\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_wlp1036\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_oepe1111\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_ocm1033\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.6.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbynet.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\xqrl.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\xquery.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\binxml.jar
PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_wls1036\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_wlp1036\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_oepe1111\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_ocm1033\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\jre\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\JDK160~1\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\AHBX\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\bin;C:\AHBX\sonar-3.5.1\bin\windows-x86-64;C:\Users\kinkar.sarkar.GDNINDIA\Downloads\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
USERNAME=kinkar.sarkar
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 8266800k(1551588k free), swap 16531744k(9417008k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.4-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_29-b11), built on Oct  3 2011 01:01:08 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Tue Jun 30 12:05:59 2015
elapsed time: 29 seconds
```

I am running application in Weblogic 10.3.6 and jsf 2.0. Please help me to solve what is wrong.

Comment: This is a known problem.  What version of `javax.jsf` JAR do you have in your `WEB-INF\lib` folder?

Comment: Please see [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067259) and [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2314977).

Comment: I have `jsf-api-2.0.jar` `javaee-api-5.jar` `primefaces-5.1.jar`. It was working fine with the same configuration previously, suddenly I am getting this issue.

Comment: Do you have `javax.jsf_1.1.0.0_1-2.jar` in your `WEB-INF\lib` folder?

Comment: Are you using Maven?  Can you try doing `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: Yes, its a maven project and I have already done with the `mvn clean install`